# Firebase Auth SDK email verification link generates 'auth/invalid-action-code'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, firebase-authentication

I'm having trouble with the Firebase Auth SDK email verification service. When a user creates an account with an email and password, a verification link is to be sent to their email address. However, when this link is clicked, I'm receiving an `auth/invalid-action-code)` error.

It may have something to do with the fact that the component is being mounted twice, as indicated by `console.log('UserManagement component mounted');` being printed twice. However, if this is the issue, I'm not really clear on how to resolve it, since this wouldn't be due to a parent component's re-rendering.

I'm using the Next.js 14 app router. The link I have set on the Firebase console is http://localhost:3000/usermgmt?mode=action&oobCode=code, and the page is stored within `src/app/usermgmt`.

Code is shown below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
'use client';

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getAuth, applyActionCode } from 'firebase/auth';
import { app } from '../../lib/firebase'; 

const UserManagement = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [oobCode, setOobCode] = useState(null);

  const auth = getAuth(app);
  const handleVerifyEmail = async (auth, actionCode) => {
    try {
      await applyActionCode(auth, actionCode);
      setMessage('Email verified successfully. You can now sign in with your email and password.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Email verification error:', error);
      handleEmailVerificationError(error);
    }
  };

  const handleEmailVerificationError = (error) => {
    switch (error.code) {
      case 'auth/expired-action-code':
        setMessage('The verification code has expired. Please request a new verification email.');
        break;
      case 'auth/invalid-action-code':
        setMessage('The verification code is invalid. Please check the code and try again.');
        break;
      case 'auth/user-disabled':
        setMessage('The user account associated with this email has been disabled.');
        break;
      case 'auth/user-not-found':
        setMessage('No user found corresponding to the verification code. The account may have been deleted.');
        break;
      default:
        setMessage('An unknown error occurred during email verification. Please try again.');
        break;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('UserManagement component mounted');
    console.log('Mode:', mode, 'Action Code:', actionCode);
  
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') return;
    
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const actionCode = urlParams.get('oobCode');
    setOobCode(actionCode);
  
    if (!actionCode) {
      setMessage('Invalid or missing code.');
      return;
    }
  
    console.log('Action Code:', actionCode);
  
    handleVerifyEmail(auth, actionCode);
    setMessage('Invalid mode.');
  }, []);  

  return (
    <div><p>{message}</p></div>
  );
};

export default UserManagement;
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I had to set the `reactStrictMode` to `false`. This was causing the component to mount twice, which is what was generating the error. This doesn't feel like a permanent fix, because `reactStrictMode` should be set to `true` for development purposes.

In `next.config.js`, I have the following:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig  = {
    // important: reactStrictMode is intended development purposes to check for any potential bugs
    // this should be set to true, but I had to set it to false for Firebase's email verification and email link sign in functions
    reactStrictMode: false, 
  }
module.exports = nextConfig
```